# How to get the nth term of a loop before the loop finishes? in java

Tags: java, loops

I have Loop and I am trying to print the nth term when the loop is less than 40, all of this without stoping the loop when is less than 40. I have tried to print it when the total is less than 40 but I it is pringting the last nth value.

All I need is th nth value when the loop drops bellow 40. I have almost complete my code but this problem is slowing me down.

**Working example, This is what the output is supposed to be**

> Please input mark: 82
>
> Please input number of days to display: 3
>
> Scheme 1
>
> (0) 82.0 (1) 73.80 (2) 66.42 (3) 59.78
>
> ***This work can be up to 6 days late before failing***.

.

.

**This is what my program outputs**

> Please input mark: 82
>
> Please input number of days to display: 3
>
> Scheme 1
>
> (0) 82.0 (1) 73.80 (2) 66.42 (3) 59.78

.

.

loop

```
         int yourValue = -1;

// Loop
while (true)
{
    if (numOfDays >= i) System.out.print("(" + i + ") ");
    System.out.printf("%.02f",total);
    System.out.print("   ");
    total = total * 0.9;
    if (total <= 20) {
        if (numOfDays >= i) System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ finalMark);
        break;
    }
    if (total < 40 && yourValue == -1) yourValue = i;
    i++;
}
System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + yourValue + " days late before failing.");
```

Comment: If you want to stop the loop when total drops below 40, you have to put the if statement inside the loop. And then you have to add a break statement to leave the loop.

Comment: but the problem with this solution is that the loop stops when the loop reaches <40 and I need the loop to stop when it reaches <20. @AlexKarlsson

Comment: Then I dont think I understand what you're after. Can you explain what it is you want to do when the value drops below 40, and what should happen when it drops below 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know for sure if I correctly understand what you problem is, but try this code:

```
int yourValue = -1;

// Loop
for(i = 0;i <= numOfDays;i++){
    System.out.print("(" + i + ") " + total+ "   ");
    total = total -5;
    //yourValue will only be filled the first time total is below 40
    if (total < 40 && yourValue == -1) yourValue = i;
    if (total<=20){
        System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ finalMark);
        break;
    }

}   // End

if (yourValue > -1) System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + yourValue + " days late before failing.");
```

If `total` falls under `40`, the value of `i` is stored in `yourValue`

If `total` falls under `20` the loop is exited and you can continue with the code behind the loop

Edit:

You can´t "get value beyond loop" but you easily can restructure you code:
(code not tested)

```
int total2 = total;
//Loop
for(i = 0;i <= numOfDays;i++){
    System.out.print("(" + i + ") " + total+ "   ");
    total -= 5;
    if (total<=20){
        System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ finalMark);
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + Math.floor((total2 – 40) / 5)+ " days late before failing.");
```

Edit2:

Note that you either have to round the value for `total` into an `integer` or you have to use a `double` for `total` (In example i expect that `total` is a `double`)

```
int i = 0;
int yourValue = -1;

while (true)
{
    if (numOfDays > i) System.out.print("(" + i + ") " + total+ "   ");
    total = total * 0.9;
    if (total <= 20) {
        if (numOfDays > i) System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ finalMark);
        break;
    }
    if (total < 40 && yourValue == -1) yourValue = i;
    i++;
}
System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + yourValue + " days late before failing.");
```

The loop is running as long as the `total` as greater than 20 or `i` is smaller than `numOfDay`, but for the output it is checked if `i` is still lower than `numOfDays`

Edit3:

```
double total2 = total;

//Loop
...
//End Loop

int counter = -1;
while(total2 >= 40) {
    counter++;
    total2 = total2 + 0.9;
}
System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + counter+ " days late before failing.");
```

Edit4:

I think I found a formula in exchange for this one `Math.floor((total2 – 40) / 5)`

try out following:

```
Math.floor((Math.log(40/total2)/log(0.9))+0.5)
```

had no time to check this out in practice but it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I  retrieve an information that is beyond the loop. for instance _when the loop ends after the 3rd nth, but total has not reach 40._ can it display days late before faling?. I rewrote the examples to make it clear @FatTony

Comment: thank you again, but how would I apply the same method, while instead of the loop going down 5, it would be going down 10% each time @FatTony

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful, but when implementing edit2 the while loop keeps runing after reaching the _numberOfDays_ and stops when (total is less than =20). It should stop when either of the two conditions are met. and is it possible to calculate _days late before faling_ as in edit1, I edited the examples and the code. sorry to bother you again. @FatTony

Comment: @lokmir Have you tried the code out? althoug the code is always running till the total is below 20 the output should be the same. This has to be since I have no idea how to calculate like in edit1. Thoug you can use an extra loop for this issu only, gonna update answer.

Comment: I have just implemented the new formula and I only had to take out the (+0.5) `Math.floor((Math.log(40/total2)/Math.log(0.9)))`. Thank you very much you solved my problem. @FatTony

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but a code which outputs your expected behavior is something like:

```
    boolean isFinished = false;
    int lastValue = 0;
    for(i = 0;i <= numOfDays;i++){
        System.out.print("(" + i + ") " + total+ "   ");
        total = total -5;

        if (total<=20){
            System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ total);
            break;
        }

        if (!isFinished && total < 40){
            isFinished = true;
            lastValue = i;
        }

    } 

    if(isFinished) {
        System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + lastValue);
    }
```

Comment: but the problem with this solution is that the loop stops when the loop reaches <40 and I need the loop to stop when it reaches <20. @turbut

Answer (score 0):

your if statement it out of the for the for loop block it suppose to be like this:

```
// Loop
    for(int i = 0;i <= numOfDays;i++){
        System.out.print("(" + i + ") " + total+ "   ");
        total = total -5;

         if (total<=20){
         System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20.
final mark="+ finalMark);
        return;
         }
        if (total < 40){
         System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + i);
        }
     }
```